# How can i override routes from a service provider in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, routes, package, service-provider

I'm making a package for use with laravel, and i'm including the routes file as specified in the documentation:

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/packages#routing

My question is this: How can i do this in a way that allows overriding these routes in App/Http/routes.php?

Essentially I want to be able to provide default routes, but not have them be compulsory. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In your package readme, add a note to ensure that they add your package Service Provider class in their app.config AFTER their Apps default RouteServiceProvider. This will ensure the user routes are given precedence

Comment: It was after the RouteServiceProvider. In fact it only worked once i put my Package service provider _before_ the default ones

Comment: And add $this->loadRoutesFrom($path); under package service provider boot function, instead of register function.